# probelm uploading image using angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular, express

im using multer with express to upload image it works for backend after testing it with postman
i dont know what type of data image should be

```
   module.exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {

 let newPost = new post({
   title: req.body.title,
   enterprise: req.body.enterprise,
   type: req.body.type,
   address: req.body.address,
   date: req.body.date,
   salary: req.body.salary,
   experience: req.body.experience,
   description: req.body.description,
   email: req.body.email,
   tags: req.body.tags,

   image: req.file.path,
   
 });
 newPost.save((err, post) => {
   if (err) res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
   res.status(200).json({ msg: post });
 });
};
```

-> but i cant get the req.file after sending form using angular

```
    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.image);
    this.newPost = {
      title: form.value.title,
      enterprise: form.value.enterprise,
      type: form.value.type,
      address: form.value.address,
      date: new Date(),
      image: formData,
      salary: form.value.salary,
      experience: form.value.experience,
      description: form.value.description,
      email: '',
      tags: form.value.tags,
    };
    console.log(this.newPost);
    this.postService.createPost(this.newPost).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How are you storing the file in this.image?

Comment: it's solved thank you all i had to do is to store the form in formdata  with the image